# Django ORM exclude result if found annihilation pair

Tags: python, django, orm

I am using [`django-activity-stream`](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream) to do my twitter clone for fun and sharpening my Django skills after daytime. Now I am using it to keep track the `action` in my system. I am tracking `hidden and liked` on the `Tweet` message

```py
Action.objects.filter(actor_content_type__id=user_ct.id,
   ...:            target_content_type__id=tweet_ct.id).values_list('target_object_id', 'target_content_type', 'verb')
Out[37]: <GFKQuerySet [('1', 28, 'hidden'), ('1', 28, 'liked')]>
```

This is `queryset` that I feed the `DjangoREST` serializer to serialize out the `response`

**Problem:**
`hidden and liked` pair is considered as annihilation case(Sorry I don't know the best term so I adopt Particle Physics term to programming) and I need `blank queryset` as an answer

**Workaround:**
Switch main `model` to one another and use `reverse` relation back to the problem

**Question:**
How can I make conditional query like annihilation pair use case?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mentioned any restrictions on performance, how about this:

```
hidden_actions = Action.objects.filter(actor_content_type__id=user_ct.id, target_content_type__id=tweet_ct.id, verb='hidden').values_list('target_object_id', flat=True)
like_actions = Action.objects.filter(actor_content_type__id=user_ct.id, target_content_type__id=tweet_ct.id, verb='liked').values_list('target_object_id', flat=True)
exclusion = set(hidden_actions) & set(like_actions)
user_action = Action.objects.filter(actor_content_type__id=user_ct.id, target_content_type__id=tweet_ct.id).exclude(target_object_id__in=exclusion).values_list('target_object_id', 'target_content_type', 'verb')
```

You'll then get in user_actions only thous that doesn't negate each other.

Comment: Please don't forget to vote the answer if it was usefull for you.

Comment: @sarit can you add some more details? In 3rd line you get only items in both sets and next this items are excluded from user actions.

Comment: Why this is true, it's semi-hard to guess at first attempt without knowing your models schema. I made changes to queries supposing that "target_object" will be the same for both actions.